# COUNTIF function in one column if it meets a condition in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to count the number of assets I have that are "In Stock" and are "MacBook Air"

See screen shot. I have tried the COUNTIF function.  But having trouble writing the condition to only count In Stock assets are MacBook Air or iPad or Window PC.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. `COUNTIF` is limited to a single criterion. Have you tried `COUNTIFS` which can manage multiple criteria?

Comment: Did you solve your problem using `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: YES!!!thank you so much.

Comment: Curious - can this work across multiple google sheets or different tabs in the same sheet?

Comment: _can this work across multiple google sheets or different tabs in the same sheet?_ Interesting question… the relationship of those other sheets/tabs to the original sum range would be key. OTOH, one might test it in < 5 minutes.